# What methods exist to measure the modulus of Elasticity of Soil?

Tags: civil-engineering

I would like to know what test can be done to quickly measure the modulus of elasticity of soil with varying parameters (density, moisture content etc).

One method I know is using the oedometer test. By varying the vertical stress and measuring the variation of strain, we can measure the modulus of elasticity.

However, the oedometer test can take a lot of time. (48 hours). Is there a way that is quicker?

Answer (score 3):

A plate loading test is relatively quick and will give you a modulus of elasticity.

There is a section on plate loading tests in EN 1997-2 (eurocode for geotechnical investigations and tests), and they are also covered by a specific execution standard, EN ISO 22476 part 13.

Answer (score 2):

You could use cone penetrometer tests and compare the results to local data or geotechnical reports.

This can give a rough estimate to begin with. In many urban areas in the U.S. there's is enough tests and reports to use.

Comment: From what I understand, the US method has failings that are accounted for in Euro standards.

Answer (score 0):

In the laboratory you might use the triaxial test or oedometer test. In the field you may be able to use the come Penetrometer test, Standard Penetration test or even dilatometer test.

Technically, from my 1st year uni understanding, soil doesn't have an elasticity modulus without water. Since all clay has water by adsorbtion, it is the water tensile stress being measured. This calls into question whether you need to examine the liquid limit of soil too.